# Notion of Independence

Tags: probability-theory

Given two random variables $X,Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, is there a notion of independence in the following sense:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} \big( \{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \in A, Y(\omega) \in B \} \big) = \mathbb{P} \big( \{ \omega \in \Omega | Y(\omega) \in B \} \big) \mathbb{P} \big( \{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \in A \} \big)  
\end{equation}

where $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$? Or is independence a statement concerning only the joint probability distributions?

Comment: This _is_ the definition of independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Sorry if this is a foolish question, but how does one use this independence to reduce $\mathbb{P}((\omega_1,\omega_2)|X(\omega_1) \in A, Y(\omega_2) \in B)$ to a product of probabilities?

Comment: Sorry, but that set is a subset of $\Omega\times\Omega$ which cannot be assigned a probability by $\mathbb P$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that $\mathbb{P}$ in the comment to be a probability measure on $\Omega \times \Omega$.

Comment: So under what probability measure is $X$ and $Y$ independent? And how does that probability measure relate to $\mathbb P$?

Comment: I think I have a crucial misunderstanding. If one says $X,Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are independent, do they mean the statement listed in the question, or that the joint probability measure on $\Omega \times \Omega$ is the product measure, or both? Or are the two statements equivalent?

Comment: Usually, one defines independence as in your question. This is however equivalent to saying that the product measure $P_X\otimes P_Y$ on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2))$ (not on $\Omega\times\Omega$) factors, i.e., $P_X\otimes P_Y(A\times B)=P_X(A)P_Y(B)$ for all Borel sets $A$ and $B$.